# AngularUI with Typeahead and Tooltip in ngTable with Custom header length undefined at scope.isOpen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, ngtable

I'm using Typeahead and Tooltip inside an ng-table with custom headers. This seems to work functionally,  and if you look at the plunker you'd never notice an issue. But, when you run the code it generates a lot of errors which can be seen in the console. The errors are generated on load, whenever I mouse over one of the rows, or when I select a value from the Typeahead. Does anyone know how to solve this?  I've been working on it for a couple days now and I haven't found a solution.

Here is the error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Scope.scope.isOpen (http://localhost:61814/app/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js:3756:31)
at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:61814/app/Scripts/angular.js:11351:18)
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:61814/app/Scripts/angular.js:13202:28)
at Object.watchExpression (<anonymous>:763:37)
at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:61814/app/Scripts/angular.js:13032:40)
at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:61814/app/Scripts/angular.js:13306:24)
at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
at done (http://localhost:61814/app/Scripts/angular.js:8797:47)
at completeRequest (http://localhost:61814/app/Scripts/angular.js:9012:7)
```

Here is my controller code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap','ngTable' ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
$scope.name = 'World';


$scope.testFilterText = "";

$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.selected = "";

$scope.testData = [{Name:"Han Solo",Role:"Smuggler"},{Name:"Luke Skywalker",Role:"Moisture Farmer"},{Name:"Princess Leia",Role:"Princess"},{Name:"Obie Wan Kenobi",Role:"Jedi Master"},{Name:"Chewbacca",Role:"Smuggler"},{Name:"Boba Fett",Role:"Bounty Hunter"},{Name:"Darth Vader",Role:"Sith Lord"},{Name:"Wedge Antilles",Role:"Pilot"},{Name:"C3PO",Role:"Protocol Droid"},{Name:"R2D2",Role:"Astromech Droid"},{Name:"Jabba The Hutt",Role:"Gangster"},{Name:"Greedo",Role:"Bounty Hunter"},{Name:"Darth Bane",Role:"Sith Lord"},{Name:"Yoda",Role:"Jedi Master"},{Name:"Mace Windu",Role:"Jedi Master"},{Name:"Commander Cody",Role:"Clone Trooper"},{Name:"Lando Calrissian",Role:"Entrepreneur"},{Name:"Mara Jade",Role:"Jedi"},{Name:"Lando Calrissian",Role:"Entrepreneur"},{Name:"Jango Fett",Role:"Bounty Hunter"},{Name:"Jar Jar Binks",Role:"Doofus"},{Name:"Darth Maul",Role:"Sith"},{Name:"Emporer Palpatine",Role:"Sith Lord"},{Name:"Qui-Gon Jinn",Role:"Jedi Master"},{Name:"Grand Moff Tarkin",Role:"Grand Moff"},{Name:"Lando Calrissian",Role:"Entrepreneur"},{Name:"Admiral Akbar",Role:"Admiral"},{Name:"IG-88",Role:"Bounty Hunter"}];


$scope.charactersTable = new ngTableParams({
  page:1,
  count: 10
},{
  counts: [10,20,50,100],
  total: $scope.testData.length,
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    var filteredData = params.filter() ?
    $filter('filter')($scope.testData, { 'Name': $scope.data.selected.Name }) :
    $scope.testData;
    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
    $scope.testData;

    $scope.myOrderedData = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
    params.total(orderedData.length);
    $defer.resolve($scope.myOrderedData);
  }
});

$scope.$watch("data.selected.Name", function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.charactersTable.reload();
                }, 100);
            }
        });


$scope.selectMatch = function (selection) {
    $scope.data.selected = selection;
    $scope.charactersTable.reload();
};

$scope.clearNameFilterText = function( evt ){
if (evt.keyCode === 13 && angular.isUndefined($scope.data.selected.Name) )  {
  $scope.charactersTable.reload();
}
}

});
```

And here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>

<script src="ng-table.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active">
<div>* To clear name filter delete previously entered text and press the Enter key.</div>
<table ng-table="charactersTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr class="main">
    <th class="sort" ng-click="charactersTable.sorting({'Name' : charactersTable.isSortBy('Name', 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'})">Character Name <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
    <th class="sort" ng-click="charactersTable.sorting({'Role' : charactersTable.isSortBy('Role', 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'})">Role <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="filters">
    <th class="input">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control passive" ng-model="data.selected" 
      typeahead="characterName as character.Name for character in testData | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
      typeahead-on-select="selectMatch($item)" ng-keypress="clearNameFilterText($event)"
      placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    </th>
    <th class="dropdown">
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
    <td><a ng-click="" class="" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-popup-delay="500" tooltip-html-unsafe='<div class="tooltip-inner vertical"><table><tr><td>Name</td><td>{{item.Name}}</td></tr><tr><td>Role</td><td>{{item.Role}}</td></tr></table></div>'>{{item.Name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{item.Role}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pQXGpO?p=preview) however you won't see the errors on plunker. the errors appear when the code is run locally or from a web server.

Thanks in advance for any help with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a defect in `typeahead`.

Workaround is this: - Initialized $scope.matches which `typeahead` itself should have done.

```
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.data.selected = "";
  $scope.matches = [];//workaround
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oYJUDK?p=preview):